# react-navigation goBack between stack navigators

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

In my React native app I am using "react-navigation": "^3.11.0".
I have top level bottomTabNavigator

```js
const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
    Main: {
        screen: balanceStack,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: I18n.t("balanceTabLabel"),
            tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor}: {tintColor: string}) => (
                <Icon name="home" style={{color: tintColor}} />
            )
        }
    },
    ServicesStack: {
        screen: servicesStack,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: I18n.t("servicesTabLabel"),
            tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor}: {tintColor: string}) => (
                <Icon name="list-box" style={{color: tintColor}} />
            )
        }
    },

}, {
    tabBarOptions: {
        activeTintColor: WHITE_COLOR,
        inactiveTintColor: WHITE_COLOR,
        style: {
            backgroundColor: PRIMARY_COLOR,
        }
    },
    backBehavior: 'history',
    swipeEnabled: true,
});
```

And stack navigators for each tab:

```js
const balanceStack = createStackNavigator({
    Balance: {
        screen: MainScreen,
    },
    FullBalance: {
        screen: FullBalanceScreen,
    },
    Payment: {
        screen: PaymentScreen,
    },
    ServiceView: {
        screen: ViewServiceScreen,
    },
}, {
    initialRouteName: 'Balance',
    headerMode: 'none',
});

const servicesStack = createStackNavigator({
    AllServices: {
        screen: AllServicesScreen,
    },
    ServiceView: {
        screen: ViewServiceScreen,
    },
    ServiceOptionAction: {
        screen: ServiceOptionsActionScreen,
    }
}, {
    initialRouteName: 'AllServices',
    headerMode: 'none',
});
```

I want that my navigation for all tabs will be common, not divided per stack.

For example 
when I navigate

Balance->FullBalanceScreen->AllServices(by clicking Services tab)->ServiceView

If I click back button (call goBack()) one time I will back to AllServices. But if I click back second time, I don't navigate to FullBalanceScreen, because it's in another stack. How can I do this?

Comment: Is this wheat that you want to move to AllServices when you press the Back button in ServiceView, and then back to ServiceView when you press the Back button in AllServices?

Comment: @hong-develop, sorry. That was mistake in post. I want back to FullBalanceScreen, not ServiceView. FullBalanceScreen is from Main stack

Comment: So you want to go to FullBalanceScreen when you press the Back button on AllServices? Where is the back button now?

Comment: Back behaviour is added manually to header of all screens like this <BackButton goBack={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}/>. I tried this.props.navigation.goBack(null) but it doesn't work as I expected too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I didn't find solution with TabNavigator and replace it with top level StackNavigator.
Also I use custom bottom Tabs component and set onPress for tab button to

```
onPress () {
        this.props.navigation.navigate (this.props.navigateRouteName)
    }
```

Where navigateRouteName is routeName to target stack route.

Answer (score 0):

If you define a custom header (either for the top level nav, or duplicated for each stack) then navigation object will have the global history (not just for each stack) so clicking back will jump between tabs

```
<A.Navigation screenOptions={{header: ({nav}) =>  <CustomHeader nav/>}>
```

and in you header you can conditionally show a back button and add handler

```
if (nav.canGoBack()) // show button
... nav.goBack() // onPress
```